# Cannot insert data in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

I am a newbie in Codeigniter. I cannot insert data into my table. I have used bootstrap files too.

These are lines from View - groups.php

```
<input type="text" name="group" id="group" placeholder="Group"> 
<button type="button" name="addgroup" class="btn btn-primary" id="add"  data-dismiss="modal">Add</button>
```

Model - groups_model.php

```
function insert_groups($dbdata) {
        $this->db->insert('groups', $dbdata);
    }
```

Controller - groups_controller.php

```
public function group()
    {
        $this->load->view('groups');
        $this->load->model('groups_model');
        if(isset($_POST['addgroup']))
        {
            $userID=  '2';
            $groupname=  $this->input->post('group');
            //$this->load->model('groups_model');
            $data=array(
                'userID'=>$userID,
                'groupname'=>$groupname
            );
            $this->groups_model->insert_groups($data);
            //var_dump($this->db->last_query());
        }

    }
}
```

My full html form is pasted below. There are a lot of comments in there.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Content</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>stylesheets/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>stylesheets/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>stylesheets/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <SCRIPT language="javascript">

//            var person;
//            var element;
//
//            function add() {
//                var e1 = document.getElementById('group').value;
//                var e2 = document.getElementById('select');
//                var o = document.createElement('option');
//                o.value = "group_body.html";
//                o.text = e1;
//                e2.options.add(o);
//
//            }

//            function goto() {
//                var index = document.getElementById('select').selectedIndex;
//                if (index.value != "select") {
//                    location = index.value;
//                }
//            }
//            function add()
//            {
//                //Create an input type dynamically.   
//                element = document.createElement("button");
//                element.className='btn btn-default';
//                var person = document.getElementById('group').value;
//                var t = document.createTextNode(person);
//                element.appendChild(t);
//                element.id=person;
//                //Assign different attributes to the element. 
////                    element.type = type;
////                    element.value = type; // Really? You want the default value to be the type string?
////                    element.name = type;  // And the name too?
//                
//                element.onclick = function() { // Note this is a function
//                  //alert(element.id);
////                   $(document).ready(function(){
////                 $("#element").click(function(){
//                     $('body').load('group_body.html');
////                 });
////            });
//                };
//
//                var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");
//                //Append the element in page (in span).  
//                foo.appendChild(element);
////                    var d = document.getElementById('fooBar');
////                    d.appendChild(i);
//            }
//
//            function copy()
//            {
//                var n1 = document.getElementById('addKeyword');
//                var n2 = document.getElementById('getKeyword');
//                n2.innerText = n1.value;
//            }

        </SCRIPT>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" name="form1">
        <div class="btn-group" id="fooBar">
            <!--            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Marketing</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Internet</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Politics</button>-->

            select a group:
            <select class="form-control" id="select" onchange="javascript:location.href = this.value;">
                <option selected value="select">select</option>
                <!--                <option>2</option>
                                <option>3</option>
                                <option>4</option>
                                <option>5</option>-->
            </select>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnAdd" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add Group</button>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Group Name</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <h5>Please enter Group Name:</h5>
                        <input type="text" name="group" id="group" placeholder="Group"> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <button type="button" name="addgroup" class="btn btn-primary" id="add"  data-dismiss="modal">Add</button>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div><!-- /.modal -->
        <div class="boxed">
            <h4>Group:<span class="label label-default" id="span"><script>document.getElementById('group').innerText = document.getElementById('span').innerText</script></span>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Edit Name</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Disable</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Delete Group</button></h4>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your keyword" id="addKeyword">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="copy()">Add</button>
                        </span>
                    </div><!-- /input-group -->
                </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
            </div>
            <h4>Keywords:</h4>
            <!--            <div class="keyword" id="getKeyword"></div>-->
        </div>
        </form>

        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>javascripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>javascripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is in last_query()? did you check query?

Comment: currently my view page is not displayed. It's saying projectname/groups is not found. In routes I've specified it by $route['groups']=groups_controller/group.

Comment: change root to `$route['groups']=groups/group`

Comment: But my controller name is groups_controller and the function name in the controller is group.

Comment: can you access groups_controller/groups in url?

Comment: Yes, I tried that and I can access it. Then why isn't it working directly?

Comment: When your view is not loading?

Comment: By writing the whole address  in url, its working. But its not working otherwise, even when I've specified it in routes.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
public function group()
    {

        $this->load->model('groups_model');
        if($this->input->post('addgroup'))
        {
            $userID=  '2';
            $groupname=  $this->input->post('group');

            $data=array(
                'userID'=>$userID,
                'groupname'=>$groupname
            );
            $this->groups_model->insert_groups($data);
                    }
$this->load->view('groups');
    }
}
```

And add action to your form :
Change

```
<form method="post" name="form1">
```

To

```
<?= form_open('yourcontroller/action')?>
//anything HTML inside your form
<?= form_close()?>
```

And you must load form helper to do this. In autoload.php

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('form');
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using button when it should be submit.

change this

```
<button type="button" name="addgroup" class="btn btn-primary" id="add"  data-dismiss="modal">Add</button>
```

to

```
<button type="submit" name="addgroup" class="btn btn-primary" id="add"  data-dismiss="modal">Add</button>
```

You have to submit the data, to get it in post

Comment: Changed it but the insert isn't happening.

Comment: Do you have form tag or form_open tag in there ?

Comment: I have form tag. I've attached full groups.php (view file) at the end of the question.

Comment: can you try a normal submit button ? <input type="submit" name="addgroup" value="Add" />. after that try print_r($data) in controller after you created the array, just to be sure it is getting data till there ?

Comment: Hey, it worked with a normal submit button. Thanks. But I have used bootstrap modal in it. With that styles of the modal, the data is not getting inserted. Why so?

Comment: try one thing echo form_submit('submit','Submit City','class="btn btn-primary" id="add"  data-dismiss="modal"'); what, i am trying to do, is to load those classes with the submit button. if the CSS, is bag based on button, then these classes may not load. in that case you need to make that class like that for submit button in CSS

Answer (score 0):

Basically you don't have action attribute in your form tag.

```
 <form method="post" name="form1">
```

You can use this expressions:

```
 <form action="yourcontroller/action" method="post" name="form1">
```

or use the Codeigniter form helper

```
 $this->load->helper('form');
 echo form_open("yourcontroller/action");
```

Hope it helps you.